# How to show div according to state of checkbox?

Tags: amp-html

I want to show a div when a checkbox is checked....

1
         Extérieur

```
    <div hidden
      [hidden]="toto">
      CHECKED 1
    </div>


    <div hidden
      [hidden]="tata">
      cHECKED 2
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: you can do with css : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZZ34CK5UZUU

Comment: good idea Bachcha Singh

Answer (score 0):

Define your conditionally showing div with an id

```
<div hidden id="toto">TOTO is checked</div>
```

Then add an action in your checkbox to toggle its visibility:

```
<input type="checkbox"
    on="change:toto.toggleVisibility" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I prefere to use a class between an id and toggleVisibility seems to be use for ids ...